Evitar que 2 columnas no se pueda repetir
tengo una tabla que estoy creando asi:
create table tbDias (
    Id int PRIMARY KEY Identity(1, 1)
  , Empl Int 
  , FechaIngreso DATE 
  , FinPeriodo DATE
  , Dias INT 
)

y lo que necesito es que no se repitan Empl y FinPeriodo a la vez.
Me refiero a que por ejemplo



Id
Empl
FechaIngreso
FinPeriodo
Dias
Correcto




1
4585
2022-08-14
2025-08-13
45
Valido


2
4585
2022-08-14
2026-08-13
15
Valido


3
5689
2003-06-19
2026-06-18
15
Valido


4
5689
2003-06-19
2026-06-18
15
NO


5
9887
2003-06-19
2026-06-18
15
Valido



Se puede repetir el Empl pero no el FinPeriodo en un mismo registro o al reves, puede haber en otro registro el mismo FinPeriodo pero no pude ser el mismo Empl
Ojala alguien pueda apoyare a corregirlo

Si te refieres a agregar una CONSTRAINT, podría tener tu respuesta.
Una CONSTRAINT en Empl y FinPeriodo, lograría que no pudieras repetir una fila en donde ambos valores sean iguales.
Sería algo como:
CONSTRAINT Unique_Empl_FinPeriodo UNIQUE (Empl, FinPeriodo)

En donde primero va el nombre de la CONSTRAINT y luego la restricción UNIQUE para ambas columnas.
Si fuera con tu tabla, sería como:
create table tbDias (
    Id int PRIMARY KEY Identity(1, 1)
  , Empl Int 
  , FechaIngreso DATE 
  , FinPeriodo DATE
  , Dias INT
  , CONSTRAINT Unique_Empl_FinPeriodo UNIQUE (Empl, FinPeriodo)
)


Si funciona bien, pero tengo el problema que en un procedimiento almacenado donde inserto en esa tabla, y por ejemplo si esta mal escrita la fecha, me manda error y reinicia la columna ID pero cuando meto un caso donde se repite, me manda este error: Cannot use the ROLLBACK statement within an INSERT-EXEC statement.
y cuando vuelvo a correrlo con otra fecha se salta un ID

Eso es un problema durante el procedimiento de guardado entonces, diferente al expuesto acá. Al momento de guardar, debes verificar que la nueva fila, cumpla las condiciones anteriormente mencionadas. Para ello, haz una nueva pregunta, con una buena descripción y demostración del error.

El hecho de que se salte IDs es por diseño. Puede parecer un problema, pero cobra sentido cuando consideras que múltiples usuarios púeden modificar la tablas al mismo tiempo y tratar de evitar lagunas generaría demasiados bloqueos para evitar modificaciones concurrentes.
